# Trying to generate 5 random items from an array but receiving an Infinite loop error in React

Tags: reactjs

The code below is supposed to generate 5 random indexes from an array, but I'm getting an infinite loop based on what I see in my console and it crashes the browser everytime. From my long hours of debugging, I realized it's the `matches.length` line in the `while loop` that's causing it. Any help on how to fix it will be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
const API_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/matches/';

  /*
  This is an async function that fetches matches from an API, generates a random selection of 5 matches,
  sets the selection to state, and updates the UI accordingly, while handling any errors that may occur.
   */
  async function generateRandomMatches() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(API_URL);
      const matches = await response.data;
      const newMatches: number[] = [];

      // The code generates a list of 5 unique random indexes between 0 and the length of matches array.
      while (newMatches.length < 5) {
        const randomIndex: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * matches.length);
        if (!newMatches.includes(randomIndex)) {
          newMatches.push(randomIndex);
        }
      }
      setSelectedMatches(newMatches);
      setShowMatches(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going after `matches.length` then the while loop conditions is wrong.
Think if `matches` containe 3 items then the while loop will never gets more then 3 and you are checking `newMatches.length < 5`.

That is why the while loop never resolve.

I added a fix by modifying the condition to `newMatches.length != matches.length`
this should solve the issue.

```js
const create = () => {
  const newMatches= [];
  const matches = [1,0,2,5,6]
  while (newMatches.length != matches.length) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * matches.length);
    if (!newMatches.includes(randomIndex)) {
      newMatches.push(randomIndex);
    }
  }
  
  return newMatches
}

console.log(create())
```

Comment: It solved the error Thank you. But let's assume I have 20 matches in the array, What if I need only 5 matches ?

Comment: Then you can use this condition in while. newMatches.length < (matches.length > 5 ? 5 : matches.length
)

Comment: Ok perfect. I just found another way of fixing it. But it's your solution that gave me the idea. I simply rapped my entire `while loop` in an if-else condition. This is what I did.

`if(matches.length < 5) {
    return;
} else {
    while (newMatches.length < 5) {
          ... the rest of the codes.
        }
}
`

Comment: But how could simple answers like this trick me? I have been struggling with this error since yesterday. Thank you @Alen.Toma

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the entire while loop in an `if-else` condition. Like so

```
        # New code
       if (matches.length < 5) {
        console.log('There are less than 5 matches available.');
        return; 
       } else {
         # Old code is still here, nothing changed.
        while (newMatches.length < 5) {
          const randomIndex: number = Math.floor(
            Math.random() * matches.length
          );
          if (!newMatches.includes(randomIndex)) {
            newMatches.push(randomIndex);
          }
        }
      }
```